# Right integration of complex JavaScript into PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

After hours and hours I can't implement JavaScript code into PHP. JavaScript code is an ad code which I need to implement in WordPress, using functions.php, but every-time I get following error:

```
identifier "key", expecting ";" in your code
```

I am trying to create shortcode first and then to use that shortcode anywhere on site, including also injection through PHP, but also directly in content. NOTICE: JavaScript code can not be changed, thus - any customization of JavaScript code is not an option, but I am out of PHP solutions.

My code:

```
function jsad_code_shortcode() {
    return '<script type="text/javascript">
                atOptions = {
                    'key' : '9f8c74bccbdb424a067d31a8a20551a3',
                    'format' : 'iframe',
                    'height' : 90,
                    'width' : 728,
                    'params' : {}
                };
                document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://versatileadvancement.com/9f8c74bccbdb424a067d31a8a20221c6/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
            </script>';
}
add_shortcode( 'jsad_code', 'ad_code_shortcode' );
```

Comment: You haven't escaped any of your single quotes.

Comment: Why does it need to be a shortcode? Shortcodes usually add some specific content in place where the shortcode is put, but your code just seems to output scripts that don't reference any elements or are specific to a location on the page. Am I wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Please don't solve it by wrapping your code with HEREDOC syntax. The problem still is that you're writing JavaScript in a PHP context, which should be avoided if possible.

Instead, write your data as a PHP array and encode it to JSON. Both JavaScript and PHP know how to interpret JSON. Use a combination of `wp_register_script` and `wp_add_inline_script` to setup your script tags.

```php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
  $at_options_data = json_encode([
    'key'    => '9f8c74bccbdb424a067d31a8a20551a3',
    'format' => 'iframe',
    'height' => 90,
    'width'  => 728,
    'params' => (object) []
  ]);

  wp_register_script('jsad', '//versatileadvancement.com/9f8c74bccbdb424a067d31a8a20221c6/invoke.js', [], null, true);
  wp_add_inline_script('jsad', "window.atOptions = {$at_options_data};", 'before');
});
```

After that the only thing that you have to do is to *enqueue* the script. This will place the script with the rest of the script tags in either the `<head>` or at the closing `</body>` tag, depending on your settings. This will also ensure that the script is only printed to the screen once.

```php
add_shortcode('jsad', function() {
  wp_enqueue_script('jsad');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code.

```
function jsad_code_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        atOptions = {
            'key' : '9f8c74bccbdb424a067d31a8a20551a3',
            'format' : 'iframe',
            'height' : 90,
            'width' : 728,
            'params' : {}
        };
        document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://versatileadvancement.com/9f8c74bccbdb424a067d31a8a20221c6/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
    </script>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode( 'jsad_code', 'ad_code_shortcode' );
```

> I think, there are some problems with your js code.

Answer (score -2):

Solution is to use **HEREDOC** syntax, so the shortcode with this kind of JS should look like as follows:

```
<?php

function shortcode() {
    return <<<EOT
    <script type="text/javascript">
                                    atOptions = {
                                    'key' : '9f8c74bccbdb424a067444665654445',
                                    'format' : 'iframe',
                                    'height' : 90,
                                    'width' : 728,
                                    'params' : {}
                                    };
                                    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://versatileadvancement.com/9f8c74bccbdb424a067d31a8a20221c6/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
                                    </script>
EOT;
}
add_shortcode( 'shortcode', 'shortcode' );
```

Thank you all...